# What shell implements POSIX semantics for the variable PS1?

Tags: sh, posix

In section 2.5.3 of [IEEE Std 1003.1, 2004 edition's sh](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html), regarding the `PS1` environment variable, it is defined:

> Each time an interactive shell is ready to read a command, the value
>   of this variable shall be subjected to parameter expansion and written
>   to standard error. The default value shall be "$ ". For users who have
>   specific additional implementation-defined privileges, the default may
>   be another, implementation-defined value. The shell shall replace each
>   instance of the character '!' in PS1 with the history file number of
>   the next command to be typed. Escaping the '!' with another '!' (that
>   is, "!!" ) shall place the literal character '!' in the prompt. This
>   volume of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001 specifies the effects of the variable
>   only for systems supporting the User Portability Utilities option.

So it seems `!` can be used in the PS1 variable to be replaced by the history file number of the next command to be typed.  If you try that in a Bourne shell implementation such as `dash`, you find it not implemented.  It's also not implemented in today's GNU bash.

Which shell implements that?

Comment: Bourne shell != POSIX shell.

Comment: Note that you are linking to an older copy of the POSIX shell specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bash implements this if you set the `POSIXLY_CORRECT` environment variable or invoke bash with the `--posix` option:

```
PS1='!$ ' POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 bash
2$ echo foo
foo
3$ !2
echo foo
foo
3$
```

Comment: Why does POSIX care for such a detail in PS1?  Any idea?

Comment: POSIX standardizes [`fc`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/fc.1p.html), and that needs a way to know the history numbers to use with this command. I have no idea why `fc` was standardized. It seems superfluous, considering that interactive shells aren't really a focus area for POSIX.

Comment: I think POSIX was just trying to acknowledge what existing shells did, interactive or no, and tried to standardize what it could. Even if `PS1` is really only important for interactive shells, `.profile` might be setting its value and you don't want every shell using a different variable name for its prompt. (Of course, the *contents* of `PS1` are so shell-dependent that it barely matters if each shell is using the same name, but still.)